# Hp Laptop HDMI display to 26" Element Flat Screen 1920x1080 Not working properly

Tags: display, hdmi

So like the title says, but the TV I'm using for a monitor has a native resolution of 1920x1080. I hook it up to my laptop and this is what I got, it goes off the screen by half an inch on all four sides, text looks HORRIBLE graphics quality is not to good and help? Using 60hz HDMI cable...

Comment: Have you updated the resolution in the display settings of your laptop for the secondary display (in this case the TV) make sure to not mirror or clone the desktops as that will not help things either.

Comment: Yes i have, ive even installed multiple display fixes from microsoft, none have worked, if it helps i have an AMD M880G with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250

Comment: What is the model/brand of your TV?

Comment: Element, ELDHt241

Comment: Have you set the TV Video Menu to HDMI while the cable is plugged in?

Comment: Yeah, just 3 min ago, i set it back to 1080p 60hz and crashed my graphics card. Gave me the blue screen of death

Comment: I'm grasping at straws at this point. Your laptop is set to push 60hz from the HDMI to the tv, right? you should be able to go into display properties while the connection is working.

Comment: Thats exactly what i did and within 3 min it crashed and shutdown my tv and laptop

Comment: I've done a bunch of searches on your TV and on your graphics card. I haven't found anything regarding BSOD or stretched screens.

Comment: Its bugging me cause I make shortfilms and I need a full 1080p for recording games and stuff

Comment: When it's hooked up and "looks horrible", is your graphics control panel reporting that it's actually displaying that resolution? And you should update the question to confirm whether or not you're using HDMI or something else. I use two TVs for my monitors and I had to go into the Video options on my televisions and change a setting that was set to "Zoom" so things were in proportion.

Comment: The laptop say its displaying 1920x1080 and the tv say 1080p 60hz Ref. and it looks terrible, i cant screenshot it because its taking the whole res not what my tv sees

Comment: I'm assuming you have a "P.Mode" (Picture mode) on your remote, does it change anything? How about the aspect ratio button?

Comment: did nothing, colors, etc, no aspect ratio button

Comment: http://www.elementelectronics.com/support_docs/eldht241/eldht241_manual.pdf
Shows you have an "Aspect" button, but perhaps yours doesn't.
If your screen shots are at the right resolution, then it's a problem with your TV's configuration and not your computer.